# Перерисовка View

Tags: android, java, view

Здравствуйте.

У меня проблема: не могу перерисовать View.

```
View view = null;
ViewPager pager = null;
TabPageIndicator tabIndicator = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    linearlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1e);
    linearlayout.addView(TabPage(0), new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.act_bar_button_home);
    but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            linearlayout.addView(TabPage(1), new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        }
    });
}

public View TabPage(int i) {
    if (i == 1) {
        pager.removeAllViews();
    }

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = new View(this);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_tab_layout, null);

    pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new CustomFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    tabIndicator = (TabPageIndicator) view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    tabIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
    tabIndicator.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return view;
}
```

При запуске программы, view отображается. А при нажатии кнопки view удаляется, но заново не появляется. В чём может быть проблема? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил сам. Просто за вместо  pager.removeAllViews(); поставил  pager.setAdapter(null); и в onClick добавил linearlayout.removeAllViews();